# Is there is a way to transclude template after the marked with ng-transclude element, but not into it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('wrapper', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-6'>" +
    "<div class='input-group'>" +
      "<input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='...'>"+
      "<div class='input-group-btn'>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Action <span class='caret'></span></button><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div></div></div></div>"
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="example">

Bootstrap markup is too complex, but opens a menu:</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        
        <!-- this part to instert -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->

</br></br>
Angular directive after the button is required (otherwise menu can not be opened):</br>
<wrapper>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</wrapper>
<!-- button failure -->

</div>
```

There is an E transclude="true" angularjs example:

```
<wrapper>
   <button ng-transclude>[transcluded content]</button>
</wrapper>
```

or

```
<wrapper>
   <button>Some</button>
   <div ng-transclude>[transcluded content]</div> <!-- additional element -->
</wrapper>
```

But I need to add inner content **after the button** element **without adding extra markup**:

```
<wrapper>
   <button>Some</button>
   <ng-transclude>[transcluded content should be here]</ng-transclude>
   <!-- <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> additioonal element is not removed -->
</wrapper>
```

I am trying to insert content

- after ng-transclude or
- instead of `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` element

Is there a simple angular way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the problem with having extra markup? Alternative would be write your own `compile`

Comment: It breaks up bootstrap input 'Action' button behaviour. Link: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns

Comment: compile it yourself then or change strategy. If you mean using `bootstrap.js` then get rid of that and use `angular-ui-bootstrap`. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I have added the snippet. By the way could you please recommend the way to add html template to the snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer is:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var ngTransclude = $(element).find('ng-transclude');
        var child = ngTransclude.children()[0];
        $(child).unwrap();
      }
```

The sample:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('wrapper', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-6'>" +
    "<div class='input-group'>" +
      "<input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='...'>"+
      "<div class='input-group-btn'>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Action <span class='caret'></span></button><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div></div></div></div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var ngTransclude = $(element).find('ng-transclude');
        var child = ngTransclude.children()[0];
        $(child).unwrap();
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="example">

Bootstrap markup is too complex, but opens a menu:</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        
        <!-- this part to instert -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->

</br></br>
Angular directive after the button is required (otherwise menu can not be opened):</br>
<wrapper>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</wrapper>
<!-- button failure -->

</div>
```